# How to implement scrollable tabs in iOS like "noties/Scrollable"?

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard

like this~
[image]

GIF:
[enter link description here][2]
https://github.com/noties/Scrollable/blob/master/art/scrollable_colorful.gif

I amm sorry I didn't say clear. I also need to implement the `vertical scroll` .See GIF~

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a collection view and set its movement as horizontal, then you can create a custom collection view cell, insert an UIButton inside it and delegate to your view to populate it with the options you want.

You can refer to this tutorial to help you:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started